# Conditional Probability and Events

Tags: probability-theory

Is A|B an event?
If not, can we call P(A|B) the probability of A|B? Because Probability refers to a function whose domain is an event space. So it wouldn't make sense to talk about the probability of something which isn't an event.

Comment: "...so it wouldn't make sense to talk about the probability of something which isn't an event". Indeed, which is why $A\vert B$ is not an event; it is not contained in the sigma-algebra of the probability space with respect to which the probability measure $P$ and the events $A$ and $B$ are defined. A new probability space needs to be defined. One way to do this is to define the conditional probability measure $P(\vert B)$, for which $P(A\vert B)$ then makes sense.

Comment: $P(A\mid B)$ is the (conditional) `probability of A` given $B$. The probability is still that of the event $A$; that is, the word "probability" applies only to $A$ and not to the "given $B$" part of the sentence. We could say instead "Given that $B$ occurred, the conditional probability of $A$ is _denoted_ as $P(A\mid B)$ and is equal to $\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}$ provided $P(B)>0$." which makes the meaning more clear, but some people would find it awkward to say so all the time. In short, you are right: $A\mid B$ is not an event and we cannot talk of its probability.

Comment: So essentially, conditional probability is not a probability of an event but rather a quotient of probabilities? Thanks. @DilipSarwate

Comment: And @ki3i, is it essential to do so? Because one can simply define conditional probability to be P(AintB)/P(B) rather than define it as some value that a probability measure assumes for a particular event.

Comment: @RaghavTalwar, if one calls something a conditional *probability* then, yes, it is necessary that there should be an appropriately defined probability space to justify such a conotation.

Comment: To sum up, A|B does not exist and P( |B) is a bona fide probability measure defined on the same probability space than P itself.